# backbone complex data modeling how to read

Tags: javascript, json, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, backbone.js

Hello all I am new in backbone and JavaScript. 
My data.json file looks like this:

```
{
"locations":
[
  {address:"2222", town:"Dallas"},{address:'3333', town:"Houston"},{}....
],

"items":
[
  {title:"shirt", price:20},{title:"shorts", price:10},{}....
]
}
```

I am populating two different Listview using jquery mobile.

---

I have created Backbone models separately for both location and item

```
Item = Backbone.Model.extend({

     default:
     {
             title:"",
         price:""
     }
});

Address = Backbone.Model.extend({

     default:
     {
         address:"",
         town:""
     }
});
```

---

I also have created Address and Item collection as following

```
Items = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   defaults: {
            model: Item
             }
});

Addresses = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   defaults: {
            model: Address
             }
});
```

---

Now How do I create my Store model which will have adress and item collection.
I guess something like this:

```
Store = Backbone.Model.extend({
    addresses:[],
    items:[],
    url:"data.json"
});
```

Also how do I populate the list view once the data is read?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a parse method to Store (http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse):

```
Store = Backbone.Model.extend({
    addresses: [],
    items: [],
    url: 'data.json'
    parse: function(response) {
        this.addresses = new Addresses(response.locations);
        this.items = new Items(response.items);
        return response;
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you could add a listener for "reset" in an initialize function, but if you're going to fetch the data anyway, I'd just use parse.

Comment: Excellent!!! Let me work on it and will let you know should I have a question for you. Thanks again..